# Laravel pop up message before redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

I am a newbie at laravel 5.1. The case is I use some message to notify user after sending message to my email. 
The code is like below:

```
$nama = input::get("name");
$email = input::get("email");
$subject = input::get("subject");
$message->from($email,$nama);
$message->to('<<your email@<<your domain>>.com')->subject($subject);
```

and it redirects to the same page with a pop up alert

```
return Redirect::to('/')->with('success',true)->with('message','Thankyou '.$nama.' for contacting me<br>I will reply asap !');
```

but the processes are that it redirects first then the message pop up and what i want is the reverse of the processes.
Is there a way to do that? All your suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: What if the message works but the redirect fail?There is a reason for that order

Comment: You have to trigger the redirection in javascript instead of php in order to do this.